# Automating jar input

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, pipe

I have a jar file which asks user the value of `n`. And adds the values entered. When the jar is executed from `cmd.exe`, works well. But when invoked from `.bat` file, it is not prompting for the input rather executes the further statements.  I tried using pipe,as,

`(echo 3
echo 10
echo 20
echo 30)| java -jar add.jar`

but didn't work.How can I automate the input?

**Note:** values are not accepted as arguments, but as a prompt.

Comment: Use the `&` operator to concatenate multiple commands, like `echo Hello&echo world`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing something about the code it's hard to tell why it's not working for you.

See below a simple working example

**Add.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Add {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            sum += value;
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**run.bat**

```
@echo off
(echo 2
echo 10
echo 20
echo 30
echo end ) | java -jar Add.jar
```

**compile and build the jar**

```
javac Add.java
echo Main-Class: Add > manifest.mf
jar cmf manifest.mf Add.jar Add.class
```

**run the batch file**

```
run.bat
```

**output**

```
sum = 2 
sum = 12
sum = 32
sum = 62
```

Comment: Works well, gives almost what I needed ! Thanks a lot :)